# Is there a point in checking if a column exists in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A column is vital for the execution of your program, so you want it to die if it doesn't exist.

```
df["column"] = df[["column1", "column2"]].apply(self._func, axis=1)
```

this will throw a KeyError if column1 or column2 doesn't exist.

```
if "vidcolumn1" in df.columns and "column2" in df.columns:
  df["column"] = df[["column1", "column2"]].apply(self._func, axis=1)
else:
  raise ValueError("Column1 and Column2 are required for ...")
```

This seems that it doesn't provide anything useful, unless you want to do something in the else part, like logging the error somewhere else in your logs.

So if you don't have a fallback for your program in case of a missing column, is there a point in using the second option?

Comment: I would actually use a try-except catching `KeyError`s.

Comment: @coldspeed I'm not sure about the usefulness of a try/except if pandas already kills the program with a useful message: this column is missing. maybe I'm missing a point..

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga, I think you've overthinking this. Who *says* you have to use the second option? There are a number of things you *can* do: let an error just happen, catch it and do something else, catch it and raise another error, or check explicitly beforehand. Which one you choose depends on what you *want to happen*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try-except` statement:

```
try:
   df["column"] = df[["column1", "column2"]].apply(self._func, axis=1)
except KeyError:
    #error log
    print ('I have problem')

    print("Column1 and Column2 are required for ...")
```

But also in your solution should be add code to `else` statement:

```
#better code for test if exist all values of set in columns
s = set(['column1','column2'])
if s.issubset(set(df.columns)):
    df["column"] = df[["column1", "column2"]].apply(self._func, axis=1)
else:
    #error log
    print ('I have problem')
    raise ValueError("Column1 and Column2 are required for ...")
```

Comment: ok, but your try/except doesn't kill the program. you'd have to raise a ValueError manually. In that case, why use it? What does it have to offer more than pandas default error.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga - hmmm, so you want second solution? Or better why do you think `if-else` is not good for you?

Comment: I think if-else is harder to read than 1 line and let pandas throw an error. But actually I might opt for the try/catch as I would like to log it somewhere else too and maybe the column is not as crucial as I thought

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga - I am now confused ;). Still not understand.

Comment: don't you think an if/else statement like my second option is harder to read than my first option and let pandas throw the error?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga - hmmm, it is hard question, because subjective in my opinion. For me it is nice, only I changed if statement. also it depends who read code - for one man it is goog readable, for another not. So if there are added some comments it is perfectly OK, because for people who seems it is hard readable it explain it.